# Clear and add content

Tags: jquery

I have the following paragraph to which content of array added

```
$('#pop').html(arr.join('<br>'))
```

I want to do like clear and add.

```
$('#pop').text('').html(arr.join('<br>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

uh.. keep using .html?

```
$('<p>').html( [1,2].join('<br>') ).html('').html( [2,3].join('<br>') )
```

Though I don't see the point of doing .html('') if you're going to replace it with new text *anyway* ...

Comment: ut it not get clear. When i say $('#pop').html(arr.join('<br>')) on click, it append content to earlier one. I check to see if arr has previous value but no arr has no issue. So issue probably in this statement. i check in IE7.

Comment: Determine if the html has content by doing if ( $('#pop').html().length ) { }

Answer (score 0):

[`text`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/text) in like [`html`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) only with HTML tags. So there is no need to call `text("")` before replacing the whole HTML content of that element with `html`.

Comment: but it not get clear. When i say $('#pop').html(arr.join('<br>')) on click, it append content to earlier one. I check to see if arr has previous value but no arr has no issue. So issue probably in this statement. i check in IE7.

Comment: @Mario: Can you give us an example?

Comment: @Mario: Post it here, it belongs to this question.